# Why $Ax=e_i$ means $A$ can be reduced row echelon form?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I'm studying proof of "Invertible Matrix Theorem". It says like below

> Let $A$ be a square $n\times n$ matrix,
>
> (g) The equation $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for each $b$ in
> $\Bbb{R}^n$.
> (a) $A$ is an invertible matrix
>
> (g) implies (a).

I read a solution, but I couldn't understand.

> Since $Ax=b$ is consistent, then there is solution for every $Ax=e_i$,
> where $e_i$ are $n\times 1$ matrices with all zeros except position
> $(i,1)$ where is $1$.
>
> This means that $A$ can be row reduced to identity matrix - inverse exist.

But why $Ax=e_i$ means $A$ can be row reduced to identity matrix? I tried to understand how can derive it, but I totally don't know. How can I approach?

Comment: I rather think that it can be column reduced to the identity matrix because $Ax$ is just a linear combination of the columns. BTW, you should add in your question that $A$ is $n\times n$. Otherwise the theorem is wrong.

Comment: I edited, but I didn't understand what's your answer.

Comment: What do you expect if you don't tell me exactly *what* you don't understand?

Comment: What is the meaning of "column reduced to the identity matrix"? I only learned row reduced matrix. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: If you know what "row reducing" means, you also know what "column reducing" means. Just apply the operations that you usually use for row reducing on the columns instead of on the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=e_i$ has a solution for each $i$, then $A$ is surjective and has full rank (since the $e_i$ form a basis for the range).  Therefore $A$ is invertible and can be row reduced to the identity.

Comment: They seem to have defined "invertible" by "can be row reduced to identity matrix". In this case, your answer doesn't help.

Comment: You're right.   This could take some proof.